# Jquery, PHP Calling other form after click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

Im just learning javascript the last days (started PHP some months ago).

So, my code make this:

**e.g**

```
 http://controljuridico.com/video01/
```

I have three files.

1. An Html file with the form.
2. A javascript file with the functions after click on "enviar" (send) button.
3. A php that process the data.

**HTML file (index.html)**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
        <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index</title>
<link href="css/css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script src="js/js.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
    </head>
      <body>
   <div id="content">
    <h1>Test.</h1>
    <h1>Step 1) choose city</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>test(*)</label>
    <hr />
    <br />
    <form name="form_data" id="form_data">

        <label>(*) City</label>
        <br />
        Medellin
        <input type="radio" name="ciudad" value="Medellin" />
        Manizales
        <input type="radio" name="ciudad" value="Manizales"/>
        Cali
        <input type="radio" name="ciudad" value="Cali"/>
        <br />
        <label>(*) Especialidad</label>
        <br />
        <input type="button"  value="Enviar" id="btn_enviar" /> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <label id="mensaje"></label>
    </form>
    <div id="resultado" ></div>
        </div>
               </body>
            </html>
```

**js.js File**

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn_enviar').click(function(){

    if( validaRadio( 'ciudad','Ciudad' ) == false) return false;


    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url :'upload.php',
        data: $('#form_data').serialize(),
        beforeSend : function(){
            $('#mensaje').html('Enviando datos...');
        },
        success: function (data){
                        $('#mensaje').html('Datos enviados  correctamente.');
                $('#resultado').html(data); 
        },
        complete: function(){
             $('#form_data').slideUp();
             $('#resultado').slideDown();

        }
    });

        }); 


          });
```

**Php File (upload.php)**

```
 <?php

  $sergu = $_POST['ciudad'];
   if ($_POST['ciudad'] == "Medellin") {
    ?>
    <label>Ciudad Ingresada:</label>
    <br />
    <label><?php echo $_POST['ciudad'] ?></label>
    <hr />
    <?php
    }else{
    echo "it is not medellin....";

   }
       ?>
```

So, this works very well but. What if I want this:

After click on "enviar" button also show another similar form at the left of this form.

I mean its just like choosing steps if you choose the step one I need another step and so on and I want that this another step just appear to the left of the previus form.

It is possible? how?

Thanks in advance for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example just hide the 'second form' when the page first loads via css like this:

```
<form id="second_form" style="display: none">...
```

and when your success function fires you remove the css like so:

```
success: function(){
  ...
  $('#second_form').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

In jquery, there is .insertBefore(). An easy way to implement what you (kind of) want, is to just echo out the new form in the php, and instead of

```
$('#resultado').html(data);
```

Do the following:

```
$(data).insertBefore('#resultado');
```

This will insert the new form, echoed out by the PHP, **under** the previous one. Ofcourse you also have to delete the

```
$('#form_data').slideUp();
```

Else, the forms will be hidden.